# Terminology for a continuous period of time

Tags: terminology, writing-style

Is there a phrase or word that best describes a continuous chunk of time , say from Nov 2012 to Dec 2016.

Another example is the blocks of time (dates: start date to end date) that you specify in a Resume when listing work experience in a chronological order.

What could such a word or phrase be ? I am thinking of "duration", maybe, but what other verbiage I can use.

Thanks !

Comment: *Period*, *interval*, or [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/interval) thereof.

Comment: I use 'timespan'.

Comment: Please provide a sentence with the word you seek left blank.

Answer (score 1):

[**interval**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interval)

1. A space between objects, points, or units, especially when making uniform amounts of separation: *We set up hurdles at intervals of 15 yards around the track.*
2. An amount of time between events, especially of uniform duration separating events in a series: *We ran laps at 30-second intervals.*

   (...)

---

[A space of time between events or states](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interval)

*a three-month interval between jobs*

---

[An intervening time](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interval)

*after his departure, there was an interval of many years without any meetings*

Comment: If we can tolerate a "software" reference, there is an example in Java of **Interval** being used in the way the OP described. Quoting  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html  *Interval is the standard implementation of an immutable time interval. A time interval represents a period of time between two instants. Intervals are inclusive of the start instant and exclusive of the end. The end instant is always greater than or equal to the start instant.*

Answer (score 0):

**Period**

> A length or portion of time:
>   ‘he had long periods of depression’.
>   **‘the period 1977–85’**.
>   ‘the training period is between 16 and 18 months’.
>   - [O-D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/period)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @K1eran ...

How about *time period*?

M-W:

[*period*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/period): a chronological division

At first blush, *time period* seems redundant, but "time" helps distinguish between this meaning of "period" and others. *Time period* refers to the expanse of time between two dates or points in time, or approximate dates or points in time. For example, November 2012 to December 2106 is a *time period*, i.e., a chronological division of time. So is the Cretaceous period. This has nothing to do with lengths of time.

For short periods of time, *time slot* works. For example, "We'll be discussing X in (or during) the 1:00 - 3:00 time slot."